# Вычислить среднюю из 5 введенных чисел. Java

Tags: java, циклы

Понимаю что можно сделать разными способами. я решил попробовать в цикле, но почему то не получается. Ввожу первое число и программа завершается, разве не должно быть чтобы просил ввести число при каждой итерации? В чем причина?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {            
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i=0;
            int sum= 0;
            for (i=0;i<5;i++);  {
                System.out.println("Input number: ");
                int num = scan.nextInt();
                sum+=num;
            }
            System.out.println(sum/i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка с запятой вконце в

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++);
```

лишняя. Уберите ее, и все заработает

Comment: Не всё заработает. Ещё деление целочисленное.